# What should our chat room be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

First of all, *yes*, we have a chat room! Come [check it out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323/operations-research)!

From the [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta):

> Every site comes with its official chat room. This is created automatically and can be reached from the Site Switcher on the top left. The chat room is the third place of your community, after main and meta. It is like the lounge where everybody can get together to discuss, complain and have fun. Personalizing this space to reflect your community and what you are is one of the small steps to take towards building an active and engaged community.

Lots of SE sites have cute/funny/punny/clever names for their chat rooms, such as:

- Academia SE ([The Ivory Tower](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower))
- Physics SE ([The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar))
- Movies and TV SE ([The Screening Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room))
- Super User ([Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access))
- Unix & Linux ([/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat))

So: What should OR.SE's chat room be called? Post one idea per answer, and let's vote!

Comment: The official list: "[Non-standard names used for main chatrooms of a site across the networks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315288/282094)".

Answer (score 6):

### Operations Research

Consider keeping it simple. I stopped visiting chat rooms a long time ago because communities obscure them behind clever insider jargon, making them difficult to discover or know what they are for. </pet peeve>

Comment: Ah, OK. I was just following the guidance in The Real Essential Questions. :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Renaming chat rooms like this is still a thing. I just don't understand it myself.

Comment: Got it. I guess if it wasn’t a thing you would have just closed the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

I’ll get us started...

### The Interior Point

Answer (score 1):

### The Open DoOR

is both welcoming and mildly punny.  I do think there is an advantage to having a name for the chat room different than the main site name.